# ASP.Net Page Works Locally But Fails When Pushed To Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

My site works to perfection locally, but whenever I push it out to the server I get an error page.  This is what the error tells me, which means nothing to me.  Can someone assist on this?

> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
> <system.web>
>     <customErrors mode="Off"/>
> </system.web>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.
>
> ```
> <configuration>
> <system.web>
>     <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
> </system.web>
> </configuration>
> ```

Comment: that is the default generic error message asp.net shows when viewing from something other than localhost. what does your logging say? what does the event viewer on the server say?

Comment: Do as the message suggests and have `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in the config, then you'll see full error message which will let you debug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard but then you are displaying possibly sensitive backend code excerpts to the public. either proper exception handling or the event viewer will show the real error message

Comment: @user1666620 - where in the event viewer are the errors logged?  I have never done this type of lookup?

Comment: If you don't have any logging built into your app your only option is to enable remote error messages long enough for you to figure out the problem, then disable it when you're done.

Comment: event viewer > windows logs > application

Comment: @user1666620 on most hosts, the events viewer isn't accessible. And when all is working, it's possible to put "LocalOnly" or just remove it to prevent any risk.

Comment: @RickS by default all unhandled exceptions appear in the event viewer

Comment: Or remote into the machine and run the app, you will see the error message that way.

Comment: @user1666620 If you don't have logging in your web.config configured, I doubt you will see anything in the event viewer.

Comment: @user1666620 & Rick S -- nothing in the event viewer to show regarding this.

Comment: Also running the app locally on the server presented the same error message as posted above.

Comment: @user1666620 - 100% positive.  I can run it locally from my PC no problems.  But running from the server, an error is displayed.

Comment: modify your web.config to show the actual error from localhost.

Comment: @user1666620 how would I do this?

Comment: Did you read the text in the page you see? Alter the `web.config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use application_error event in global.asax to capture exception and then write exception in separate error.txt log file.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs ex) 
    { 
        Exception e = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
            if (!e.Message.ToUpper().Contains("FILE DOES NOT EXIST."))
            {
               //This function is user defined Method which accepts string as inpout and writes it to error.txt file with date and time.
               WriteTo_ERROR_TXT_File(e.ToString());                              

              //Redirect to custom error display page               
               Server.Transfer("Error.aspx");    
            }        

    }

public void WriteTo_ERROR_TXT_File(string inputString)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Error.txt"), true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(inputString);
        }

    }
```

In this way you will capture all the errors , If you want more robust solution then you can use **ELMAH**

Comment: I get a compile error of 'The name 'WriteTo_error_TXT_File' does not exist in the current context

Comment: This could be a compiler error too. Then this code won't work.

Comment: @user1666620 - where would the error log be created?

Comment: @user2676140 as comments says in Application_Error .."This function is user defined Method..." that means we need to write separate method manually for it...but no worries I have added code for that too..in my edit please check it...